# Is the body of requires block unevaluated context?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Is the body of a concept definition or require block unevaluated context? eg. can I use `std::declval` safely?

```
template<typename T>
concept bool SomeConcept = requires(T a) {
    { a.someFunction(std::declval<int>()) } -> int;
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. From [temp.constr.expr], wording as of [N4641](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4641.pdf):

> An *expression constraint* is a constraint that specifies a requirement on the formation of an *expression* `E` through substitution of template arguments. An expression constraint is satisfied if substitution yielding `E` did not fail. **Within an expression constraint, `E` is an unevaluated operand** (Clause 5).

So using `declval` should be fine.

Alternatively, you could just create objects of the types you need since in the context of requirements, we're not actually constructing anything:

```
template<typename T>
concept bool SomeConcept = requires(T a, int i) {
    { a.someFunction(std::move(i)) } -> int;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Barry! By the way, is there any other advantages to receive variable rather than the more readable syntax? Is it just better practice or there is some pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Probably a little early to talk about what's better practice. Personally, I'd like to avoid all the pre-Concepts metaprogramming hacks where possible.